# Asynchronous cursor execution in Snowflake using GoLang

Tags: go, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need the ability to run multiple queries asynchronously and be able to cancel them if they are over a custom timeout period. I have been able to find solutions in python by using the cursor to start the query execution with no_results set to true but the snowflake driver thru the sql interface doesn't allow such operation.

Any recommendations? Thanks

Comment: This is a really broad question that delves deeply into thread management.

Comment: My question was related more into the capabilities of the gosnowflake driver. But looks like they haven't implemented it yet https://github.com/snowflakedb/gosnowflake/blob/1605e50f6382eea57ec3fd3d66fcbd31604548df/connection.go#L208

Comment: but you could just start different go routines with a query in parallel and you can also cancel them after some time with a context https://github.com/snowflakedb/gosnowflake/blob/master/doc.go#L165

Comment: @tclass yes, indeed that is the approach we will follow after some conversations here, I already tested it using a cancel context and calling the cancel function in the case of the timeout and it properly cancels the query on the Snowflake side. This originally was not the option as we wanted to follow the original approach when using Athena that involved kicking off the queries, getting their ids and having another process that will control the completion of the queries and cancel them if necessary or collect the results.